# Updating indicator's script won't affect all charts (pine-script)

Tags: pine-script

I have a 4 chart structure to which I added a custom indicator (to each chart).

When I open the Pine Script pane below, make changes to that script/indicator and save, it doesn't reflect in the charts at all.

I have to manually remove the script from each individual chart and re-add it for the change to take effect.

Isn't there a way to "refresh" all custom indicators in charts according to the changes made in the script?

Comment: What kind of changes are you talking about? Because in my case, changes do affect all charts. Can you give us an example?

Comment: Well, it seems like that I forgot another element in the "spread" of the changes amongst other chart windows. In fact, I have to click upload (save) chart. Then all other charts on other windows update code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When having multiple browser windows with TradingView's charts. In order to propagate certain indicator code changes, not only you have to save the code, you also have to save the layout (the cloud icon on the top bar)